# SELinux and cryptsetup: chown failed and can't access temporary keystore

Tags: encryption, luks, selinux, cryptsetup

I am trying to set up SELinux and an encrypted additional partition that I mount at startup using a systemd service.

If I run SELinux in permissive mode, everything runs ok (partition is correctly mounted, data can be accessed and service runs properly).

If I run SELinux in enforcing mode (enforcing=1), I am not able to mount such partition with the error:

```
/dev/mapper/temporary-cryptsetup-1808: chown failed: Permission denied
sh[1777]: Failed to open temporary keystore device.
sh[1777]: Command failed with code 5: Input/output error
```

Any ideas to fix that?

Audit2allow does not return any additional rules to be added

Edit 1 after @A.B comment:

I used cat instead of tail. Audit2allow suggest no additional allow rules, but analyzing the log file I find some denial of interest:

```
type=AVC msg=audit(1624863678.748:72): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=1894 comm="cryptsetup" path="/dev/dm-0" dev="devtmpfs" ino=5388 scontext=system_u:system_r:sysadm_t:s0-s15:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:fixed_disk_device_t:s15:c0.c1023 tclass=blk_file permissive=1
type=AVC msg=audit(1624863678.748:73): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=1894 comm="cryptsetup" name="dm-0" dev="devtmpfs" ino=5388 scontext=system_u:system_r:sysadm_t:s0-s15:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:fixed_disk_device_t:s15:c0.c1023 tclass=blk_file permissive=1
```

Searching for every "cryptsetup" entry in the audit log I find this:

```
~# cat /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep "cryptsetup"
type=AVC msg=audit(1624863678.748:72): avc:  denied  { getattr } for  pid=1894 comm="cryptsetup" path="/dev/dm-0" dev="devtmpfs" ino=5388 scontext=system_u:system_r:sysadm_t:s0-s15:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:fixed_disk_device_t:s15:c0.c1023 tclass=blk_file permissive=1
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1624863678.748:72): arch=14 syscall=195 success=yes exit=0 a0=bfebd34c a1=bfebd2e0 a2=bfebd2e0 a3=bfebd370 items=0 ppid=1891 pid=1894 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="cryptsetup" exe="/usr/sbin/cryptsetup" subj=system_u:system_r:sysadm_t:s0-s15:c0.c1023 key=(null)
type=AVC msg=audit(1624863678.748:73): avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=1894 comm="cryptsetup" name="dm-0" dev="devtmpfs" ino=5388 scontext=system_u:system_r:sysadm_t:s0-s15:c0.c1023 tcontext=system_u:object_r:fixed_disk_device_t:s15:c0.c1023 tclass=blk_file permissive=1
type=SYSCALL msg=audit(1624863678.748:73): arch=14 syscall=5 success=yes exit=6 a0=bfebf7ac a1=131000 a2=0 a3=10022cc0 items=0 ppid=1891 pid=1894 auid=4294967295 uid=0 gid=0 euid=0 suid=0 fsuid=0 egid=0 sgid=0 fsgid=0 tty=(none) ses=4294967295 comm="cryptsetup" exe="/usr/sbin/cryptsetup" subj=system_u:system_r:sysadm_t:s0-s15:c0.c1023 key=(null)
```

Edit 2: Looking for any changes in the refpolicy repo, I found [this Novembre 2020 commit](https://github.com/SELinuxProject/refpolicy/commit/7122154c1906bf9564325ad3f4c4821bdd2562de) and [this February 2021 commit](https://github.com/SELinuxProject/refpolicy/commit/ed5d860a8c6dd5eb47fb73a67a12585f3261a855). I don't know if they may apply to the case in hand.

Comment: Relevant logs in /var/log/audit/ and there are tools like audit2why to help

Comment: As mentioned, neither analyzing /var/log/audit nor using audit2* commands brings any further info

Comment: Some events (AVC) are not logged by default. You can get them logged with `semodule -DB` (and refilter them with -B alone). https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/using_selinux/troubleshooting-problems-related-to-selinux_using-selinux

Comment: You can also check manually for entries with denied without audit2allow (eg: tail -F /var/log/audit/audit.log | grep -w denied)

Comment: @A.B I have updated the question accordingly to the new findings in the audit.log file. Comment character limit does not allow me to reply in line here. Please check the edit and let me know if there any fix I can introduce (i.e. a cryptsetup policy). Thank you for the help

Comment: FWIW: you should never put additional data from questions in comments in comments yourself: you have to add them in the question, as you did.

Comment: And you should have stuck to what I wrote: grep denied, not cryptsetup but in realtime to avoid all the past events. Or you might get incomplete results. Anyway I did my part. I didn't say I could solve it (my favorite method involves reproducing the problem, which I can't with my current setup).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved assigning to cryptsetup the `lvm_exec_t` context.

In the `lvm.fc` file cryptsetup was defined as `/bin/cryptsetup` but I had to change it to `/usr/sbin/cryptsetup` where it actually was.